# Creating a 4d matrix full of zeros in python, numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am trying to create a 4 dimensional matrix in python using the following code;

```
import numpy as np
rho=np.zeros(2,2,2,2)
```

But I get the following error;

```
    rho=np.zeros(2,2,2,2)
TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

This seems to work in matlab, but not here. Any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of passing 4 arguments, pass one argument, a tuple of four elements:

```
>>> rho=np.zeros((2,2,2,2))
>>> rho
array([[[[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]],


       [[[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]]])
>>> rho.shape
(2, 2, 2, 2)
```

The [call signature](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) is `zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C')`, and so it's trying to interpret the first 2 as the shape, the second 2 as the type, the third 2 as the storage order, and then it doesn't know what to do with the last 2.